# Why doesn't the Earth lose its magnetic properties?

Tags: electromagnetism, earth, geomagnetism

I learnt in junior high that magnets, when exposed to heat, usually tend to lose their magnetism. Similarly, the Earth's core is also hot, but it doesn't lead to the loss of magnetism of Earth. Am I missing something or is there any fault in my understanding?